# advanced-installer generated installer doesn't set odbc connection

Tags: windows-installer, odbc, vmware, advanced-installer

I used advanced installer to generate an installer(exe) of a windows application. During the installation, a ODBC connection is created.

The installer works on a windows 8 in VMware. But it could not create the ODBC connection in a real windows 8 machine.

I have compared the log file of windows installation. The content are the same. And I noticed that there are 3 actions relating ODBC connection in both logs.

> **Action start** 11:28:03: *AI_OdbcInstall*.
>   ...
>   Action 11:28:03: AI_OdbcRollback. Executing rollback ODBC resources
>   **Action start** 11:28:03: *AI_OdbcRollback*.
>   AI_OdbcRollback: Resource: Executing rollback ODBC resources
>   **Action ended** 11:28:03: *AI_OdbcRollback*. Return value 1.
>   ...
>   Action 11:28:03: AI_OdbcConfig. Executing install ODBC resources
>   **Action start** 11:28:03: *AI_OdbcConfig*.
>   AI_OdbcConfig: Resource: Executing install ODBC resources
>   **Action ended** 11:28:03: *AI_OdbcConfig*. Return value 1.
>   ...
>   **Action ended** 11:28:03: *AI_OdbcInstall*. Return value 1.

Is there any way to find out the error? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need to take a look at the installation log files and possibly add the tag "windows-installer" to this question.

Comment: Thanks, jbudreau. I have compared logs from both VMware installation(ODBC connection created) and physical windows 8 installation (ODBC connection not created). The content are the same. And both logs show 4 actions related to odbc connection (see my updated post)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from a website. It seems that, the cause is a limitation of Advanced Installer vision>10

**Solution**
Go to "Custom Actions" page and add a "Set installer property" 
custom action with sequence, scheduled after **Wizard Dialogs Stage -> Searches** and **Install Execution Stage -> Searches** actions group, like this:

```
Property: *AI_USE_STD_ODBC_MGR*  
Value: *1*
```

**Source**
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=27912